# How to add a caption or description to a graphic

Tags: graphics, captions

I'm writing a paper for one of my classes that requires me to include some graphs.  I've been able to include the desired graphs without too much trouble, and I've been able to center them and size them the way I want without too much trouble either.  The part that I can't figure out is how to add a description to each figure, preferably at the bottom of each one.  I realize that the code is probably a mess overall and that there are probably much easier ways to do it, but I'm still very new at Latex and I basically have to look up how to do each step.  If anyone could let me know how to add a caption to the bottom of each graphic and what package or packages I need to use to do that, it would be much appreciated.  The code for the graphics is included below.

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{First5CatalanNumbers.png}
\hspace{1.3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{First10CatalanNumbers.png}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{First15CatalanNumbers.png}
\hspace{1.3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{First20CatalanNumbers.png}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{First25CatalanNumbers.png}
\hspace{1.3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{First30CatalanNumbers.png}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `figure` is used instead of `center`, then one simply can use `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\hspace{1.3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\caption{heading}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\hspace{1.3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\caption{heading}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\hspace{1.3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\caption{heading}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Alternatively the `caption` package and `\captionof{}{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\hspace{1.3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\hspace{1.3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\hspace{1.3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Each image with its own caption:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.17]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will let me do one caption for each set of two images that I have.  Worst case scenario I can make this work.  But how do I add a caption for each image, for 6 total, but still keep the layout of the images the same.  In other words, I like the way that the graphs are spaced and set up, I just want to add a caption to each one individually.  Thanks.

Comment: @AlexAdinolfi Only seconds ago I wrote an answer how to place two things besides each other: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484408/185617 If you place each image in a separate minipage you can have a `\captionof` for each of them

Comment: @AlexAdinolfi See edited answer

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you very much, this solves the problem!