# Make two objects (a graph and an algorithm) lined next to each other in a single column article

Tags: graphics, two-column, multicolumn

I have a single column article, and I have a algorithm and a graph arranged like following:
[image]

I am just wondering can I do something like this:

[image]

Any solution is welcome. Thanks a lot.

Here is my algorithm:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Iterative GM-estimator}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\STATE Input($\mathbf{X};\mathbf{y}$)
\STATE $k = 0; \epsilon=10^{-5};$
\STATE Initialize($\mathbf{Q}^{(k)};\mathbf{w}^{(k)};s^{(k)};\delta^{(k)};\mathbf{w};k_{max};$)
\WHILE {$k<k_{max}$ and $\delta^{(k)}>\epsilon$}

    \STATE $\mathbf{a}^{(k+1)} = \left( \mathbf{X}^H \mathbf{Q}^k \mathbf{X} \right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^H \mathbf{Q}^k \mathbf{y}$
    \STATE $\mathbf{y}^{(k+1)} = \mathbf{Xa}^{(k+1)}$
    \STATE $\mathbf{r_S}^{(k+1)} = (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{y}^{(k+1)})/(s^{(k)}\mathbf{w})$
    \STATE $\mathbf{Q}^{(k+1)} = q(\mathbf{r_S}^{(k+1)})$;
    \STATE $s^{(k+1)} = s(\mathbf{r_S}^{(k+1)})$;
    \STATE $\delta^{(k+1)} = \mathbf{X}^{(k+1)}-\mathbf{X}^{(k)}$;
    \STATE $k = k+1$;
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\label{algo_gm}
\end{algorithm}
```

Here is my packages:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}    

%\newcommand{\subparagraph}{}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}


\journal{European Journal of Radiology}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minipages can do this:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}    

%\newcommand{\subparagraph}{}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}

\usepackage{caption}


\journal{European Journal of Radiology}

\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Iterative GM-estimator}
\begin{algorithmic} 
\STATE Input($\mathbf{X};\mathbf{y}$)
\STATE $k = 0; \epsilon=10^{-5};$
\STATE Initialize($\mathbf{Q}^{(k)};\mathbf{w}^{(k)};s^{(k)};\delta^{(k)};\mathbf{w};k_{max};$)
\WHILE {$k<k_{max}$ and $\delta^{(k)}>\epsilon$}

    \STATE $\mathbf{a}^{(k+1)} = \left( \mathbf{X}^H \mathbf{Q}^k \mathbf{X} \right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^H \mathbf{Q}^k \mathbf{y}$
    \STATE $\mathbf{y}^{(k+1)} = \mathbf{Xa}^{(k+1)}$
    \STATE $\mathbf{r_S}^{(k+1)} = (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{y}^{(k+1)})/(s^{(k)}\mathbf{w})$
    \STATE $\mathbf{Q}^{(k+1)} = q(\mathbf{r_S}^{(k+1)})$;
    \STATE $s^{(k+1)} = s(\mathbf{r_S}^{(k+1)})$;
    \STATE $\delta^{(k+1)} = \mathbf{X}^{(k+1)}-\mathbf{X}^{(k)}$;
    \STATE $k = k+1$;
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\label{algo_gm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{heading}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It gives error: ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

Comment: @NickXTsui Can you show the code you tried? My example works without problems for me.

Comment: Just replace your first "code for algorithm
", with \begin{algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

Comment: @NickXTsui Please show the complete code you tried - guessing things you might or might not have in your code is a waste of time. For example I don't know which packages you use.

Comment: See updates of the post. Does that help? Have you tried what I suggested? Yes when I use your code exactly, that works. However, even if I replace "code for algorithm" with \begin{algorithm} \end{algorithm}, it gives the same error.

Comment: @NickXTsui see my edited answer. Why do you have `graphicx` three times?

Comment: I see. However, when I paste in my algorithm code, it is not working. Can you perhaps take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @NickXTsui Show the code that is not working

Comment: See the updated post. Thanks!

Comment: @NickXTsui Again you show only code pieces, but not the complete code that is not working. Put together they work fine.

Comment: I showed all the algorithm part. Is there anything else I should be showing you? I am not sure.

Comment: @NickXTsui A small but compilable document like I have in my answer.